# Problem on using rgbdslam with kinect connected remotely on the network

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, openni, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone
I am trying to run rgbdslam on pc with kinect data captured with another laptop on network. Firstly i establish the network. Then i run roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch on the laptop which the kinect is conected to it. Then i roslaunch rgbdslam rgbdslam.launch on th PC. The laptop just capture the kinect data and send them on network to PC. But with no error there is no image on rgbdslam GUI and it doesn't work. I appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221593/problem-on-using-rgbdslam-with-kinect-connected-remotely-on-the-network/) by [Morteza](https://answers.ros.org/users/20070/morteza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2015-11-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-04-11**:
Do you receive the data on the PC? Can you check with e.g. `rostopic hz /camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw` or by displaying with "image_view"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try increasing the value of subscriber queue size. You can also use rviz or rostopic to see whether any messages are coming in.

---

Originally posted by [tango_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25854/tango_explorer/) with karma: 16 on 2016-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0